# Javascript -> symfony controller request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, post

I have HomeController.php with function :

```
public function foo(Request $request) : Response
    {
        do something
    }
```

Also i have routes.yaml to acces this controller

```
app_foo:
    path: /foo
    controller: App\Controller\HomeController::foo
```

The question is, how can i execute foo() by clicking on link generated in javascript dynamically.
What have i tried:

```
<a href="{{ url(app_foo) }}"> link </a>
```

and

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/app_foo",

    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: first approach did nothing, but second with ajax returned 500

Comment: I bet it's not true that it did _nothing_. I bet it output some HTML. What you probably mean is that the HTML it output wasn't _useful_ - but we still need to know what the HTML _looked like_ (the source code, not how the browser rendered it) if you want us to explain _why_ it didn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your route with JS, you need to expose it with [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)
Your route will become:

```yaml
app_foo:
    path: /foo
    controller: App\Controller\HomeController::foo
    options:
        expose: true
```

In your template (or parent template) add

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

And your javascript :

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: Routing.generate("app_foo"),

    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

If you use webpack.encore to generate JS, tell me, it's a bit different :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `event` object that you receive in the function callback and call `event.preventDefault();` to stop the browser's native click handler, and also `$(this).attr('href')` to get the `href` portion of the URL so that you aren't hard-coding it. I haven't tried this code, but it should generally work:

```js
        $(document).on('click', 'a', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $(this).attr('href'),

                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
```